# Existing figure is not found in the current working directory Latex

Tags: packages, miktex, texmaker, eps, epstopdf

This question has been asked many times, but I still cannot import a figure with .eps extension to the Latex document.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figures/figure_name}
\end{figure}
```

Error I recieve: `` ! LaTeX Error: File `figures/figure_name' ``  not found.
My .eps file is located in current working directory. Note that I do not include .eps extension when calling the figure.

What I have tried:

1. Use LaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX to compile. Because I read that pdfLaTeX does not work with .eps files
2. I tried to use`\usepackage{epstopdf}` and also `\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}` with pdfLaTeX to convert .eps to .pdf. Note that after I try to convert, no pdf file is found in my working directory either.
3. I have refreshed FNDB via MikTeX console after installing `epstopdf` and adding the figure to the directory

and nothing helps.

What else can be a reason for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: if your figure is really in the current working directory, then you should use `{figure_name}`   and not `{figures/figure_name}`

Comment: from the directory where you run pdftex (not necessarily the directory containing your document) is the path to the figure `figures/figure_name.pdf` ?  your description makes it sound as if the path is `figure_name.pdf` ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are right! This solves the problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the answer, I have solved the problem already